# What is the difference between ROLAP and a Data warehouse?

Tags: data-warehouse, rolap

I am really confused between the definition of ROLAP and a Data warehouse. When we load aggregate data in relational tables can we call this ROLAP? Or is ROLAP a reporting tool?

Comment: ROLAP is a data warehousing concept, e.g.: http://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/molap-rolap.html

Answer (score 3):

**Data warehouse**: Data warehousing is a technology that aggregates structured data from one or more sources so that it can be compared and analyzed for greater business intelligence.

Many types of business data are analyzed via data warehouses. The need for a data warehouse often becomes evident when analytic requirements run afoul of the ongoing performance of operational databases. Running a complex query on a database requires the database to enter a temporary fixed state. This is often untenable for transactional databases.

A data warehouse is employed to do the analytic work, leaving the transactional database free to focus on transactions. The other benefits of a data warehouse are the ability to analyze data from multiple sources and to negotiate differences in storage schema using the ETL process.

---

**ROLAP**: Cubes in a data warehouse are stored in three different modes. A relational storage model is called Relational Online Analytical Processing mode or ROLAP, while a Multidimensional Online Analytical processing mode is called MOLAP. When dimensions are stored in a combination of the two modes then it is known as Hybrid Online Analytical Processing mode or HOLAP.

The advantages of ROLAP model is it can handle a large amount of data and can leverage all the functionalities of the relational database. The disadvantages are that the performance is slow and each ROLAP report is an SQL query with all the limitations of the genre. It is also limited by SQL functionalities. ROLAP vendors have tried to mitigate this problem by building into the tool out-of-the-box complex functions as well as providing the users with an ability to define their own functions.

Answer (score 0):

A datawarehouse mainly focuses on the structure and organization of the data whereas ROLAP (or an OLAP) concentrates on the usage of the data. A data warehouse mainly serves as a repository to store data (historical) that can be used for analysis. An OLAP is the processing that can be used to analyze and evaluate data that is stored in a warehouse.